# Login password verification returning unknown errors

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, bcrypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I have set up a simple to Login script that authenticates users and also creates a session based of the the username. I am getting an error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: $password in /var/www/checklogin.php on
>   line 51

I don't understand how I am getting this error because I do not have a $password any where. Only thing that I have related to `$password` is `$row['password']` and that is the name of the field in php. Any tips? This is the code:

```
//The Select Statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = :username"; 
$query_params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);
try{
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    die($e->getMessage());
}
$login_ok = false;

//This is password encryption for register_script.php
$Blowfish_Pre = '$2y$17$';
$Allowed_Chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./';
$Chars_Len = 63;
$salt = "";
for($x=0;$x<10000;$x++){
    $salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$Chars_Len)];
}
$bcrypt = $Blowfish_Pre . $salt; 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row){
    $password_check = crypt($_POST['password'] . $bcrypt);
    if($password_check === $row['password']){
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}       
if($login_ok){
    unset($row['password']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row;
    header("Location: login_success.php");
    die ("redirecting to: login_success.php");
}
```

Pretty much the idea I have is that in authenticating users, you must recreate the the salt/hash, in my case I must recreate how I used the bcrypt to encrypt my passwords. I don't really know where to turn at the point of the project.

Edit 1:  Line 51 is :

```
if($password_check === $row['password'])
```

Comment: What is your line 51 in checklogin.php?

Comment: I just added the line with edit

Comment: Are you sure it says `$password` and not `password`?

Comment: http://puu.sh/1GqvA that is a push link. it is a screen shot of my putty command line screen.

Comment: @mati $password_check = crypt($_POST['password'] . $bcrypt); yes

Comment: You could try var_dump'ing $row.